# Destruction of Instance Surrounded by Parentheses

Tags: c++, destructor

I should `delete` `new` instances in C++, right?

```
class C {
public:
    void hello() {...};
};
```

If I have an instance of the class above, I may have to use it like

```
C* c = new C();
c->hello();
delete c;
```

right? How about this:

```
(new C())->hell();
```

Can I do this? Is `destructor` automatically called and free the memory?

Comment: No. Destructor will not be called and memory is lost. Never do it like that. You can create temporary object on stack.

Comment: Why would things be freed in the second sample without `delete`, but not if you have named pointer? Always delete what you new.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah... Side effect of Java...?

Comment: Java code is fine, so long as you are writing Java. It's best not to draw parallels with C++.

Answer (score 4):

No, destructor is not called automatically because you never call `delete`. However you can create a smart pointer that will do it for you at one go:

```
::std::make_unique<C>()->helo();
```

Comment: Does `::` precedes `std`? Which header file contains `make_unique`?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi `::` in front of the identifier states that this identifier refers to something in global namespace. `make_unique` is from `<memory>`, just like `::std::unique_ptr` it creates.

Comment: Can I omit the first `::`?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Technically you can (and most of the programmers seem to do so). But in real life programming prefixing  with `::` all the identifiers from the global namespace (not only `std`) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In modern c++ there is no reason to `new`-up resources anymore. Instead you can use the `memory` library as following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    C(int a) : _a(a) { }
    void printA() { std::cout << _a << std::endl; }
private:
    int _a;
};

std::make_unique<C>(3)->printA(); // prints 3

// or via variable
auto c = std::make_unique<C>(123);
c->printA(); // prints 123
```

In here, the resources are already taken care off and you can't forget deleting something you allocated somewhere else.

Comment: What can I do if a constructor has parameters?

Comment: I updated it to reflect the treatment of ctor arguments

Comment: `std::make_unique` accepts any number of arguments and passes them to class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No in the second case the destructor will not be called and also you will have memory leak. The destructor of a dynamically allocated objects is called only when explicitly calling `delete`.